# Bootstrap class for not invalid-feedback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a class which I can use for representing !invalid-feedback? What I am trying to do is, I want to have a placeholder under my form input and tell the user that this field needs to only have 3 characters and if the validation fails, I will add a a div with a class of invalid-feedback. I want them to be mutually exclusive so it's either the placeholder or the invalid-feedback.

So for example,

```
<form:input path="ac" required="required"
    class="form-control text-uppercase" maxlength="3" />
<small class="form-text text-muted">Only three characters are allowed</small>
<div class="invalid-feedback">AC is required</div>
```

in the following block, if the user is either entering the data or if the value is valid, I want to show what's in the <small> tag, if the form is submitted and if there is a validation error, I want to show what's in the invalid-feedback div.

So, is there a class in Bootstrap which is basically !invalid-feedback? Is it valid-feedback? isValid? Can this be done with just using styles and not Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

There are Bootstrap classes to indicate a [field has an error](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/#server-side) but since you're asking to display errors in a non-Bootstrap way (i.e. by hiding and showing different tags) you'll have to roll your own validation using Javascript.

Here is one way that monitors the status of the input field and hides/shows the `<small>` and `div.invalid-feedback` elements. (Note that this is just a proof-of-concept, and doesn't deal well with all possible ways of the user interacting with the input field.)

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 3) {
        $('.invalid-feedback').hide()
        $('small').show()
    } else {
        $('.invalid-feedback').show()
        $('small').hide()
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
<input path="ac" required="required"
    class="form-control text-uppercase" maxlength="3" />
<small class="form-text text-muted">Only three characters are allowed</small>
<div class="invalid-feedback">AC is required</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I was actually looking to achieve this with just Bootstrap styles, not with JS/jQuery.